# convert any date format to DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a file which contains date column. It contains date in multiple format. I have to convert all to `DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss`.

Wrote below query but not getting an expected result :-

```
scala> val a = Seq(("01-Jul-2019"),("01-Jul-2019 00:01:05"),("Jul-01-2019"),("2019-07-01")).toDF("create_dts").select(col("create_dts"))
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [create_dts: string]

scala>

scala> val r = a.withColumn("create_dts", date_format(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").cast("timestamp"), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")).show


+-------------------+
|         create_dts|
+-------------------+
|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|               null|
|               null|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `coalesce` function to get first non-null conversion:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def to_timestamp_multiple(s: Column, formats: Seq[String]): Column = {
    coalesce(formats.map(fmt => to_timestamp(s, fmt)):_*)
}
a.withColumn("converted", date_format(to_timestamp_multiple($"create_dts",
      Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    .cast("timestamp"), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")).show
```

Result is:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|          create_dts|          converted|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|         01-Jul-2019|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|01-Jul-2019 00:01:05|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|         Jul-01-2019|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|          2019-07-01|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

it is working fine now by using `when` condition

```
val a = Seq(("01-Jul-2019"),("01-07-2019")).toDF("create_dts")
val r = a.withColumn("create_dts",when(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").cast("date").isNotNull,date_format(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").cast("date"), "dd-MM-yyyy")).when(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MM-yyyy").cast("date").isNotNull,date_format(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MM-yyyy").cast("date"), "dd-MM-yyyy")))
```